# Blazor: Can´t access objects in component from inherited baseclass

Tags: blazor

got some problems with accessing a list from a component with my inherited baseclass.

My baseclass looks like this:

```
public class MapBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected HttpClient Http { get; set; }
    public List<Thing> things;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        things = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Thing>>("data/things-data.json");
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
       //doing stuff with my things list and it works perfectly.
    }
```

}

Everything works fine in my baseclass and i can accessing(it got items in it) the "things" list from my OnAfterRenderAsync method. Then i have a component that inherit the baseclass:

```
@inherits MapBase

<div id="myComponent">
    <select>
        @foreach (var thing in things)
        {
            <option>@thing</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

The webpage just stops working because of the things list(it works when i remove the reference to the things list). What is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `things` instance is not initialized, so it's null and that throw a `NullReferenceException`, Initialized the instance or check for null before the `@foreach`

```cs
public List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
```

Or

```cs
@if (things != null)
{     
     @foreach (var thing in things)
     {
        <option>@thing</option>
     }
}
```

Comment: I will add a little clarification here: `OnInitializedAsync` should be thought of as TWO (or more) operations - stuff that happens when the component is created, and stuff that happens __after__ the `await` call.The component will render twice - once when `things` is null, then again when `things` has been populated from the API call.